# Asynchronous update of `message.user` in react-native-gifted-chat does not trigger rerender properly

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

### Background

I am using [react-native-gifted-chat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat) to implement a chat feature in my app. The messages and user information come from different sources. That has caused me to implement my chat feature as the following:

1. Fetch and render the message first (`setMessages(...)`)
2. Fetch user information asynchronously in the background
3. When the user information is fetched, update all the user's messages in the `messages` state (the `messages` array is copied and the state is updated with `setMessages` to ensure it will trigger a rerender)

### Expected Behavior

The users' avatars show as fallback avatars at first, and then rerender as the correct ones.

### Actual Behavior

The users' avatars show as fallback avatars at first, and then not all of them rerender correctly - some of them are still fallback avatars, despite that a correct `message.user.avatar` is provided.

### Minimal Issue Reproducer

https://snack.expo.dev/@int_max/gited-chat-avatar-rerender-repro?platform=web

### What I have tried

- Recreating the `message.user` object to make sure the underlying component, which might depend on that object itself instead of its properties, will rerender. (Not working.)
- Recreating the `message` object (similar as above). (Not working.)
- Recreating the entire `message` object through deep copying (effectively the combination of the above two). (Not working.)